# Why does SumConvergence return unevaluated?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I am trying to confirm that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^2(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$
diverges.

However, when I try to use `SumConvergence` or `Sum` I get an unevaluated expression. Why so?

I tried

```
 SumConvergence[Cos[n]^2/Sqrt[n], n]
 SumConvergence[(1 + Cos[2*n])/(2*Sqrt[n]), n] 
 Sum[ Cos[n]^2/Sqrt[n], {n, 1, Infinity}]
 Sum[(1 + Cos[n])/(2 Sqrt[n]), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

However, it does not have any problems with just:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$
which correctly states that it converges.

Also, is there a way to make *Mathematica* display the test that was successful? And if the **Ratio Test** is used, is there a way to display the sequence that was chosen to compare it to?

I should add that I am using *Mathematica* 11.2.0 on Windows 10 x64

Comment: While it is expected that MA should work in these simple examples, I would like to point out that even for very simple series it is not trivial or even impossible to verify the convergence. See this extended discussion https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65858/series-whose-convergence-is-not-known and on two very interesting solutions for $\sum\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n}$, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282259/is-the-series-sum-n-sin-nn-n-convergent and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823816/is-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-sin-nnn-convergent

Comment: Why do you want to confirm? The harmonic series diverges and so does this one. Or is it just sporting Mathematica  ;-)

Comment: @yarchik thanks for the links. I will take a look!

Answer (score 3):

```
FullSimplify[ForAll[x, x \[Element] Reals, Cos[x]^2 + Cos[x + 1]^2 > 1/4]]
FullSimplify[Cos[x]^2/Sqrt[x] >= Cos[x]^2/Sqrt[x + 1], x >= 1]
```

Taking these two facts and assuming $x\geq1$, then we can also say that: $\frac{cos(x)^2+cos(x+1)^2}{\sqrt{x+1}}\geq\frac{1/4}{\sqrt{x+1}}$.

Thus, every two terms of the `Sum` must be greater than or equal to $\frac{1/4}{\sqrt{x+1}}$, which obviously diverges. That said, this is more of an outline than a formal proof, so please double check it.

It does not seem as though any particular combination of options will make *Mathematica* directly yield this result. Even if there were, *Mathematica* is only rarely capable of explaining the reasons for its results, and it does not appear that there is any mechanism for extracting such information from `SumConvergence`.

Comment: What is interesting is that *Mathematica* can determine the convergence of $$\sum\frac1{2\sqrt{n}}$$ and the divergence of $$\sum\frac{\cos(2n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$ but cannot determine the divergence of $$\sum\frac{1+\cos(2n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$ which is just a simple step...

Comment: It's worth noting that it's probably possible to represent the sum of the `Cos` to an odd power as a sort of alternating series, so it doesn't surprise me that it can handle it directly. `Sum[1/n]` is a pretty classic result at this point, so I'm also not surprised it can handle it. I am somewhat surprised that it doesn't the form in your question at all though. Also, the first sum there diverges as well.

Comment: It seems *M* does not have a robust implementation of the comparison test. E.g. `SumConvergence` fails on `Cos[n]^2/(n^5 Sqrt[n])` but not on `Cos[n]^2/n^5`.

Comment: @DMH16 One cannot conclude that if a sum can be decomposed into divergent plus an unknown sum, then the original sum is divergent. Further reasoning is needed, so it's not a simple step, though in the case of `(2 + Cos[n])/n`, it is a first-year calc. step, which `SumConvergence` fails to take.

Comment: @MichaelE2 well, it’s not an unknown sum... the sum of $\cos(n)/n$ is known to converge by Dirichlet’s Test, and the same can be said for  $\cos(2n)/ \sqrt{n}$. In fact even *Mathematica* confirms that $\cos(2n)/ \sqrt{n}$ converges. So it really is an easy step to confirm that diverges because the sum of a divergent series with a convergent one gives a divergent series...

Comment: @DMH16 Ok that's a simple step, but my *M* (V11.2) says it doesn't know the conv/div of `Cos[2n]/Sqrt[n]`. (I'm ignoring what is known mathematically and just considering what *M* says it knows. Since `Cos[2n]/Sqrt[n]` is unknown to M, it's not an simple step. It was unclear to me what you meant about its divergence in your first comment, since *M* fails for me.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I’m sorry, I didn’t explain my self very well in the first comment.

Answer (score 2):

**This is an extended comment rather than an answer.**

Since the sums only evaluate using [`Regularization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Regularization.html) and "Regularization affects only results for divergent sums and products", the implication is that the sums diverge.

```
Sum[Cos[n]^2/Sqrt[n], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

[image]

```
sum1 = Sum[Cos[n]^2/Sqrt[n], {n, 1, Infinity},
  Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
```

[image]

```
sum1 // N // Chop

(* -0.990145 *)

Sum[(1 + Cos[n])/(2 Sqrt[n]), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

[image]

```
sum2 = Sum[(1 + Cos[n])/(2 Sqrt[n]), {n, 1, Infinity},
  Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
```

[image]

```
sum2 // N // Chop

(* -0.827232 *)
```

Comment: My take on the implication is that when you get results for the sum from the two methods and they are different, then the sum is divergent (or there is a bug).  But in each case, in `sum1` and `sum2`, one of the default-method sum does not evaluate to a result.  It seems impossible to decide whether the unevaluated sum is equal to the the one that yielded a result.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - if in fact the sums are divergent then they are NOT equal. The regularized sum is then the regularization of a divergent sum.

Comment: Yes, but my point is about the case in which the normal sum does not evaluate (with no divergence message) and the regularized sum yields a result. Then there are two possibilities. (1) The sum is convergent but the value of the sum cannot be computed by `Sum`; however, its true value is equal to the result of regularization, and we can't tell that. (2) The sum is divergent and its divergence cannot be computed by `Sum`. A non-result like `Sum[Cos[n]^2/Sqrt[n], {n, 1, Infinity}]` is no evidence. One cannot conclude the sum is divergent based on it.

Comment: @Michael E2: If the series with nonnegative terms were convergent, then its sum (=regularized sum)) is nonnegative. However, the values are  -0.990145 and -0.827232.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, of course. I noticed that even before Bob posted. That does not appear to be Bob's argument, though.